# Why did Saber choose to return to her original timeline in Fate/stay night (Saber route) anime?

Tags: fate-stay-night

Just finished *Fate/stay night* (Saber route).

I'm wondering why Saber chose to return to her original timeline only to give up and die, rather than stay with Shirou. Is it because of the consequences of leaving the Holy Grail undestroyed (what's wrong with leaving it alone, anyway?) or because she returned to fight, only to decide to give up as she returned?

Comment: I was probably wrong. Edited the title.

Answer (score 3):

I don't remember the exact details from the anime adaptation, but in the original Visual Novel, Shirou gets tempted by Kirei into using the power of the Grail to change his past, but he refuses, choosing to stay on the path he's chosen. His resolve makes Saber rethink her wish, and ends up accepting her past. Also, the grail was tainted by Angra Mainiu, it had to be destroyed. It could NOT grant proper wishes, it'd twist any wish and manifest it as destruction.